# tweepy.Client is not working, after last tweeter update

Tags: python, tweepy, twitterapi-python

Twitter send a massage that I need to subscribe to reactivate my account. I subscribed for the free plane and, NONE of my code is working anymore. I am using `tweepy.Clint`

```
client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=BEARER_TOKEN)
```

showing this error for any request

```
Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal.
```

I tried to regenerate all tokens and nothing happened